# Confusion about definition of derivative in Rudin 5.5 proof of chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am confused by the first part of this theorem 5.5 in Baby Rudin where it states by the definition of the derivative, we have $$f(t)-f(x)=(t-x)[f'(x)+u(t)]$$
where $u(t)\to 0$ as $t\to x$. I understand this intuitively, but I feel Rudin pulled this out of thin air as the definition we have been given is $$f'(x)=\lim_{t\to x}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$$

Formally, how does this fact follow from the limit definition of the derivative we have been given?

[image]

Comment: Just define $u(t)$ as $\frac {f(t)-f(x)} {t-x} -f'(x)$ and notice that $u(t) \to 0$ as $ t \to x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folksy informal proof of the chain rule looks simply like this:
$$(g \circ f)'(x) = \lim_{t \to x} \frac{g(f(t)) - g(f(x))}{t-x}
= \lim_{t \to x} \frac{g(f(t)) - g(f(x))}{f(t)-f(x)} \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}
= g'(f(x)) f'(x).$$
The trouble with this is that as $t$ tends to $x$ we may have $f(t) - f(x) = 0$ infinitely often, so the factor
$$\frac{g(f(t)) - g(f(x))}{f(t)-f(x)}$$ does not strictly speaking have a well-defined limit, because it is not even defined in a neighborhood of $x$.

Rudin is describing a way of ignoring this issue. He is simply rephrasing the definition of derivative in the way described in the other answers.

A very similar way of fixing the folksy proof is to just patch up the definition of the first factor in the natural way. Let
$$
q(s) = \begin{cases} \frac{g(s) - g(y)}{s-y} &: s \neq y \\ g'(y) &: s = y\end{cases}.
$$
It follows from the definition of derivative that $q$ is continuous, and we have
$$\frac{g(f(t)) - g(f(x))}{t - x} = q(f(t)) \frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t - x}.$$
This holds if $f(t) \neq f(x)$ by inspection, and if $f(t) = f(x)$ then it holds because both sides are zero. Now it is legal to apply the product rule for limits and the chain rule follows.

This is really the same as what Rudin is doing: $v(s) = q(s) - g'(y)$.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply!

Answer (score 3):

Let $u(t)$ be $\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-f’(x)$ and $0$ if $t-x=0$ clearly $u(t)\to 0$  as $t\to x$ and we have $f(t)-f(x)=(t-x)[f’(x)+u(t)]$ for all $t$ .

Answer (score 1):

If you define$$u(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-f'(x)&\text{ if }t\ne x\\0&\text{ if }t=x,\end{cases}$$then $\lim_{t\to x}u(t)=0$ and you always have $f(t)-f(x)=(t-x)\bigl(f'(x)+u(t)\bigr)$.